# best method for interactive site map

Tags: html, interactive

I've been asked to make an interactive site map for a local development which has a few houses on it, so users can click on the relevant house within an aerial site layout, and see it's details listed, and whether or not it's sold.

Staff need to be able to mark houses as 'sold'.

It's been a while since I've done anything like this - in the past I would have used flash and had the sold status updated via actionscript and php, but things have moved on. What are some of the most popular methods now?

I've included an example below which is a lot larger scale than what I'm looking to do, but the same principle. I can't work out how they did it though, and I'd really like it to be vector so it can be zoomed into without losing quality, plus have the option to animate things like the popup bubbles etc if the tech allows.

Also, I'd probably be looking to include this in a Kirby CMS site, and hopefully have the updating done through that, but it's fairly flexible.

Thoughts appreciated!

https://www.redrow.co.uk/developments/the-sycamores-162433/interactive-site-map-4803v1

Comment: Where's the example?

Comment: Whoops, forgot the link! Added now, thanks!